# How to split my program across multiple classes?

Tags: java, swing, class

The aim is to have a simple Java web browser built out of swing components, and to have the JEditorPane stored in one class, and the address bar and to-be-added JButtons to be stored in another class. How do I get them to interact with each other like they did when everything was in the same class?

Original Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class JavaBrowser extends JFrame {

private JTextField addressBar;
private JEditorPane contentDisplay;

public JavaBrowser() {

    super("Java Browser v1.0");

    addressBar = new JTextField("Enter URL here, then press enter");
    addressBar.addActionListener(       
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            loadContent(event.getActionCommand());
        }
    }   
    );

    add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    contentDisplay = new JEditorPane();
    contentDisplay.setEditable(false);
    contentDisplay.addHyperlinkListener(
            new HyperlinkListener() {
                public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
                        if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                        loadContent(event.getURL().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    add(new JScrollPane(contentDisplay), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(500, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void loadContent(String userInput) {
    try
    {
        contentDisplay.setPage(userInput);
        addressBar.setText(userInput);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid URL entered in the address bar!");
    }
}

}
```

JEditorPane Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class JavaBrowser extends JFrame {

private JEditorPane contentDisplay;

public JavaBrowser() {

    super("Java Browser v1.0");

    contentDisplay = new JEditorPane();
    contentDisplay.setEditable(false);
    contentDisplay.addHyperlinkListener(
            new HyperlinkListener() {
                public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
                    if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                        loadContent(event.getURL().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    add(new JScrollPane(contentDisplay), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(500, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void loadContent(String userInput) {
    try
    {
        contentDisplay.setPage(userInput);
           ToolBar.getAddressBar().setText(userInput);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid URL entered in the address bar!");
    }
}

}
```

ToolBar Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ToolBar {

private static JTextField addressBar;

public static JTextField getAddressBar() {
    return addressBar;
}

public void setAddressBar(JTextField addressBar) {
    this.addressBar = addressBar;
}



public ToolBar() {

    JavaBrowser jb = new JavaBrowser();

    addressBar = new JTextField("Enter URL here, then press enter");
    addressBar.addActionListener(       
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            jb.loadContent(event.getActionCommand());
        }
    }   
    );

    jb.add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}

}
```

Comment: 1: create an instance of each View-Controller class you envision, 
2: create references between them, 
3: they can now call each other's functions.

Comment: Also, move to JavaFX and use their built in WebView ;-) Swing is being replaced by JavaFX and building your own browser is not only extremely complicated, it's reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ok, so now everything seems to be playing nice, however my address bar no longer appears. All I did was add "JavaBrowser jb = new JavaBrowser();" and the same for toolbar in various places. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're creating new instances of your objects within each other, but that's not right. You should make one instance of each and then create references between them. Let's say object A needs to communicate with object B, then you add a field in A to hold an instance of class B and call the setter to make it point to the instance of B you made. For the layout issues: create a JPanel with a specific Layout manager (BorderLayout is probably best for you) and add that to the frame. Add all your other components to the JPanel instead of directly to the frame.

Comment: The short answer is composition. (which means making an instance of one class inside the other. You would then control that instance based on the methods inside that class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ToolBar` class is not any type of `Component`. It should probably extend `JPanel`. You should also probably add Layout Managers to your JPanels. In fact, you should probably use more JPanels instead of stuffing things inside a JFrame.

Moreover, you should split your code in 3 classes: one class for the browser, one for the toolbar and one that controls both. In that one controlling class, make an instance of `JavaBrowser` and an instance of `ToolBar`. Update the ToolBar class so it can store a reference to a JavaBrowser and expand the constructor of ToolBar to expect an instance of JavaBrowser. Put both things in a JPanel in the controlling class and put that JPanel in the JFrame.

My Swing is a bit rusty but here's an effort:

```
public class MainApp extends JFrame{
    public MainApp(){
        JavaBrowser browser = new JavaBrowser();
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(browser);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(browser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(panel);
    }
}

public class ToolBar extends JPanel{
    public ToolBar(final JavaBrowser browser){
        super(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField addressBar = new JTextField("...");
        addressBar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ browser.loadContent(event.getActionCommand()); }
        });
        add(addressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class JavaBrowser extends JPanel{
    public JavaBrowser(){
        super(new BorderLayout());
        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
        // set up all your stuff like properties and listeners to the editor
        add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // other methods such as loadContent(...)
}
```

Then at some point in some class (usually in the psvm), you launch your Swing code on the Swing UI thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r)`, where r is a `Runnable` which creates an instance of `Controller`, sets its size and calls `setVisible(true)`.